# How to wipe the past allocated space from Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, partitioning, reinstall

[image: partition list screenshot]

I uninstalled Ubuntu recently and I want to reinstall it. Before I can reinstall it, I need to make some unallocated space. But I'm confused where was the past "ubuntu" came from?

Comment: Are you installing in addition to another operating system (Like Windows), or are you installing it as the only OS on the computer?

Comment: I am installing it as a dual boot.

Comment: I installed ubuntu in the past and I want to use that space and more. Because when I uninstalled ubuntu last time, I forgot to format the space that it consumed into a "windows type"

Comment: Why do you need unallocated space? Is the installer not able to partition the disk as you wish? Please do not post screenshots of terminal text. Paste it [into your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/911680/edit) directly. https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals

Comment: I recommend you see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) or [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315914/step-by-step-guide-to-partition-an-external-hdd-in-two-file-formats) for basic information on disk partitioning. If you still have questions, you'll probably have to ask a new question with details about your current configuration, since your current question is very thin on details that are needed to give more than a generic answer.

Comment: In `terminal` you can type `sudo fdisk -l` and that might give you the information you need (depending on how your removed Ubuntu). Otherwise, you'll need to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, start `gparted`. If you need help with `gparted`, take a current-window-only screenshot and edit it into your question and I'll take a look for you.